Process file with a name that starts with "-" (unzip in this case)
I am running Debian bullseye on a VPS.
I want to mass-check integrity of many zip files auto-downloaded from a website. Unfortunately, some of these files have names that start with -, such as -example-file.zip.
When I do unzip -t -example-file.zip or unzip -t "-example-file.zip", unzip sees the filename as options and does not actually try to process this file. The same happens with other commands (tried touch).
Apart from a mass-renaming script in a non-Shell language, how can I process such files?

You have a few options:

Prefix with ./ or an Absolute Path
unzip -t ./-example-file.zip


Use -- to Stop Option Parsing
unzip -t -- -example-file.zip




(3) doesn't work, I actually tried unzip -t *.zip before writing this question. Option processing seems to happen AFTER wildcard expansion. For the same reason I am suspicious of (4) and (5), as option processing might also happen after the variable abd find expansions. However, (1) worked like a charm, thanks!!! I did not try (2).

@MikhailRamendik 5 won't work either. 4 only works because we're finding inside the . directory, so the path will be ./something. find may also find other files called -example-file.zip in subdirectories
